# How to map different actions to Web API methods that would have same signature

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to create a REST service using Web Api best practices and I came to a situation I don't know how to handle.

Imagine I have groups and inside of each group I have users.

This is how my GroupController looks like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/groups")]
public class GroupsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    // I also want to add endpoint which fetches all the users inside of group and I'd like to do it like this:
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}/users")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

As you can see, my second method won't compile since we can not have two methods with the same signature in the same class.

My route template looks like the standart one:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultRouting",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
```

I know that I can add a route which maps also action method name but I was wondering if there's a better way for achieving my goal. I'd like to stick to the best principles for writing RESTful services. As I know, one of the suggestions is to avoid custom action names since this is more common for WCF services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix `MapHttpRoute()` style routing configuration and attribute-based routing. It's simpler to use one or the other (I prefer attribute-based as it's explicit and allows for clearer class method names).

You also seem to not be calling the method necessary to enable attribute-based routing on your config - `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`.

Finally, I'd rename your methods as follows to ensure there is no clash in the method signatures: `GetGroups(int id)`and `GetUsersForGroup(int id)`

Comment: So, would then I be able to hit "GetUsersForGroup(int id)" by navigating to api/v1/groups/1/usersforgroup ?

Comment: No, your attribute has the path as `api/v1/groups/1/users`. This is also why I prefer attribute routing as the route is not dependent on the method name.

Comment: I meant would it hit "GetUsers(int id)" method and it actually does. That is why I marked your response as an answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that's because the URL matches one of the routes on the controller, even if it is a partial match in this case.

Comment: As far as I know if you make a call to a 'GET' end point with custom action name it maps the phrase after the 'Get' in my case it maps users.

Comment: If you use attribute routing exclusively, this should not be the case as the endpoint to method map will be dictated entirely by the attributes afaik. I would not rely on the ASP.NET naming convention as it restricts refactoring possibilities if you need to be more expressive in your method signatures (which in itself breaks SOLID guidelines).